# Generate text with n subsequences

Tags: combinatorics, algorithms

For given natural number $n$ generate not so long text made of not so big number of signs, which has exactly $n$ different sub-sequences. But remember that empty sub-sequence is also the sub-sequence. We consider sub-sequences to be different if their text is different. For instance sequence “ioi” has seven sub-sequences (i,o,ii,io,oii,ioi and empty sub-sequence).

Is there any math formula or algorithm to solve it?
I'm trying to solve it for almost one day and I still have no idea for solution

Comment: Is oii really a subsequence of ioi? Then you probably have a different idea of what "subsequence" means than I do. Or is it a typo (and supposed to be oi)?

Comment: I probably used the wrong word. I'm from Poland and I'm not sure about translation. But I meant oii

Comment: Then what happened to oi?

Comment: oi equals to io

Comment: But ioi is not equal to oii? Now you've really lost me. What exactly is your definition?

Comment: This is a problem from an ongoing competition (https://sio2.mimuw.edu.pl/c/oi26-1/p/pod/). Please do not answer this question until November 13.